# is it possible to modify all elements of a list in java?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have a list of `String`s and I want to perform the same operation on all of the `String`s in the list.

Is it possible without performing a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [apache commons util](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#forAllDo).

Comment: Link is broken and I can't figure out how to format the url properly to get in answer. The answer points to CollectionUtils.forAllDo(java.util.Collection collection, Closure closure)

Answer (score 9):

Well *something's* got to loop, somewhere - if you want to abstract that into your own method, you could do so, but I don't believe there's anything built into the framework.

[Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) has various methods in `Iterables` to perform projections etc, but if you want to *modify* the list on each step, I'm not sure there's any support for that. Again, you could write your own method (extremely simply) should you wish to.

When Java eventually gets closures, this sort of thing will become a lot more reasonable - at the moment, specifying the "something" operation is often more effort than it's worth compared with hard-coding the loop, unfortunately.

Comment: what do you mean by `closures` in `When Java eventually gets closures`?

Comment: @foampile: Well, closures exist in Java in the form of anonymous classes already, but lambda expressions in Java 8 will make them a lot more palatable. If you have no idea what a closure is, it would take far too long to explain in a comment - I suggest you search the web.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it recursively, but I don't see why you'd want to.   You may be able to find something similar to Python's map function (which, behind the scenes, would either be a loop or a recursive method)

Also note that strings are immutable - so you'll have to create 'copies' anyway.

Answer (score 4):

No. You must loop through the list.

```
 for(String s:yourlist){
       dooperation(s);
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Why do you not want to perform a loop?

If it's computational complexity, then no, it's unavoidable. All methods will essentially boil down to iterating over every item in the list.

If it's because you want something cleaner, then the answer depends on what you think is cleaner. There are various libraries that add some form of functional map, which would end up with something like:

```
map(list, new Mapper<String, String>() {
    public String map(String input) {
        return doSomethingToString(input);
    }
);
```

This is obviously more long winded and complex than a simple loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i += 1) {
    list[i] = doSomethingToString(list[i]);
}
```

But it does offer reusability.

```
map(list, new DoSomethingToStringMapper());
map(otherlist, new DoSomethingToStringMapper());
```

But probably you don't need this. A simple loop would be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

sorry, you have to iterate through the list somehow, and the best way is in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you mean by no loop, this may interest you:
a map function for java.

http://www.gubatron.com/blog/2010/08/31/map-function-in-java/

...there's still a loop down inside of it.

Answer (score 2):

In Java you'll need to iterate over the elements in the Collection and apply the method.  I know Groovy offers the * syntax to do this.  You could create an interface for your functions e.g. with an apply method and write a method which takes your Collection and the interface containing the function to apply if you want to add some general API for doing this.  But you'll need the iteration somewhere!

Answer (score 2):

Use divide and conquer with multithreaded traversal. Make sure you return new/immutable transformed collection objects (if you want to avoid concurrency issues), and then you can finally merge (may be using another thread which will wake up after all the worker threads finished transformer tasks on the divided lists?).
If lack of memory in creating these intermediate collections, then synchronize on your source collection. Thats the best you can do.

Comment: When giving answers like this that are abstract and complex, an example goes a long way.

Answer (score 1):

No you have to use a loop for that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to perform the operation on each reference variable to the Strings in the List, so a loop is required.

If its at the List level, obviously there are some operations (removeAll, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The java **API** provides special class to store and manipulate group of objects. One Such Class is  ***Arraylist***

Note that **Arraylist** class is in **java.util.ArrayList**

Create an ArrayList as you would any objects.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
//..
ArrayList ajay = new ArrayList();
```

Here

- ArrayList -> Class
- ajay -> object

You can optionally specify a capacity and type of objects the **Arraylist** will hold:

```
ArrayList ajay<String> = new ArrayList<String>(10);
```

The Arraylist class provides a number of useful methods for manipulating objects..

The **add()** method adds new objects to the ArrayList.And **remove()** method remove objects from the List..

Sample code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        ArrayList<String> ajay = new ArrayList<String>();
        ajay.add("Red");
        ajay.add("Blue");
        ajay.add("Green");
        ajay.add("Orange");
        ajay.remove("Green");

        System.out.println(colors);
    }
}
```

Output for this Code:

```
[Red,Blue,Orange]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Accepted answer link is broken and solution offered is deprecated:**

[`CollectionUtils::forAllDo`](http://@Deprecated%20public%20static%20%3CT,C%20extends%20Closure%3C?%20super%20T%3E%3E%20C%20forAllDo(Iterable%3CT%3E%20collection,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20C%20closure)%20Deprecated.%20since%204.1,%20use%20IterableUtils.forEach(Iterable,%20Closure)%20instead%20Executes%20the%20given%20closure%20on%20each%20element%20in%20the%20collection.%20If%20the%20input%20collection%20or%20closure%20is%20null,%20there%20is%20no%20change%20made.)

> **@Deprecated**
>
> `public static <T,C extends Closure<? super T>> C forAllDo(Iterable<T> collection, C closure)`
>
> **Deprecated. since 4.1, use [`IterableUtils.forEach(Iterable, Closure)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/IterableUtils.html#forEach(java.lang.Iterable,%20org.apache.commons.collections4.Closure)) instead**
>   Executes the given closure on each element in the collection.
>   If the input collection or closure is null, there is no change made.

---

You can use [`IterableUtils::forEach(Closure c)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/IterableUtils.html#forEach(java.lang.Iterable,%20org.apache.commons.collections4.Closure))

> Applies the closure to each element of the provided iterable.